# combining 2 separate objects as different multires levels

Tags: sculpting, geometry, multiresolution

I have 2 different objects. they used to be 1 object, a sculpt with a multires modifier. that file was lost, but i have the 2 exported meshes (low and high poly). since they used to be 1 object with a multires modifier, I would like to know if there is any method I can use to redefine them as multires levels of 1 object?
(so that the low res is the base, and the sculpt the high res, both are the same object)

I tried the reshape (subdivided the low res to the correct vert count, and retargeted the shape to the sculpt) but that just broke the whole thing. any ideas? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

update: this tutorial proved to be useful. if anyone else has a similar issue:
https://youtu.be/MU7EQjauKNo

Comment: Welcome :) Would you be able to support this answer with a brief explanation? Link-only answers are generally considered low effort on this forum, with more comprehensive answers being preferred. Thanks!